How to received APIs at the same time in Flutter application
In my flutter application, I am receiving API and processing it to change UI, but their are number of devices from which I am receiving API data, how to handle the data if 2 or more API data receives at the same time.【I have only 1 URL, each device sending API data to this URL】
In init function I am calling fetchData and processing the data in the same function:
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadContainers(); 

    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 200), (Timer t) => fetchData(ipAddress));
 
  }

fetchData function:
 Future<void> fetchData(String? ipAddress) async {

    if (ipAddress == null) {
      return;
    }

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://$ipAddress:5000/api/get_data'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
      final List<dynamic> data = responseBody['data'];
      .
      .
      .

Python Script running in the background:
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # This will enable CORS for all routes

# To store the last received JSON data
received_data = None

@app.route('/api/data_status', methods=['GET','POST'])
def pos_status():
    global received_data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Check if the request content type is application/json
        if request.content_type != 'application/json; charset=UTF-8':
            return jsonify({"error": "Unsupported Media Type"}), 415

        # Get JSON data from request
        received_data = request.get_json()
        if received_data is None:
            return jsonify({"error": "Bad Request, No JSON data found"}), 400

        # Process JSON data if needed
        print("Received JSON data:", received_data)

        # Example response data
        response_data = {
            'reply': 'data received',
        }
        return jsonify(response_data)

@app.route('/api/get_data', methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    if received_data:
        return jsonify(received_data), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({"error": "No data available"}), 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000,debug=True)


Flutter application should process the API data received at the same time.
